# Limit input text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tawk.to

I am using Tawk to chat in my website. I want to limit the number of text to 11 digits.

```
<input type="text" id="prechat2Field" title="Phone" value="" class="textInput" maxlength="20" placeholder=" Phone">
```

I can't change their core files. Can it be done using Jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override property `maxlength` for that element:

```js
 $('#prechat2Field').prop('maxlength',11);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="prechat2Field" title="Phone" value="" class="textInput" maxlength="20" placeholder=" Phone">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `maxlength` attr like below via jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#prechat2Field").attr('maxlength',"11");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="prechat2Field" title="Phone" value="" class="textInput" maxlength="20" placeholder=" Phone">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="prechat2Field" title="Phone" value="" class="textInput" maxlength="20" placeholder=" Phone">
```

To do this by jQuery:

```
function restrict_length(value, maxChar){
    $(value).attr('maxlength',maxChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it (without `maxlength`):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('prechat2Field')
input.onkeypress = function(ev) {
  if (input.value.length >= 11) {
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="prechat2Field" value="" placeholder="Phone">
```